# How to prevent <lightning-input-field> from changing the column width of Custom Datatable in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, html, lightning-datatable, datatable, html5

I have developed an LWC which uses custom datatable. In that datatable, If I use `<lightning-record-edit-form>` and `<lightning-input-field>`, the column widths change. Please see the screenshots.

**Screenshot 1:**

The 3rd column is using `<lightning-input-field>`. (column alignment is improper)

[image: sc1]

**Screenshot 2:**

The 3rd column is using `<lightning-input type="text">`. (column alignment is proper)

[image: sc2]

I wish to use `<lightning-input-field>` for column 3 and I wish to align the columns perfectly as seen in screenshot 2.

I have tried using `<div class="slds-grid">` and `<lightning-layout>` but both didn't work. Please help. Thank You!

**CSS Code:**

```css
.set-width {
    width: 90%;
}
```

**HTML Code:**

```html
<!-- this is the datatable -->
                    <table class="slds-m-left_large">
                        <!-- this is the header of the datatable -->
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>
                                    <div class="set-width" title="Field">Field</div>
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    <div class="set-width" title="Operator">Operator</div>
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    <div class="set-width" title="Input Value">Input Value</div>
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <!-- this is the body of the datatable -->
                        <tbody>
                            <!-- iterate over wrapper list -->
                            <template iterator:item={wrapperListCopy}>
                                <!-- set index as the key for each item -->
                                <tr key={item.value.index}>
                                    <!-- this is the field combobox -->
                                    <td>
                                        <lightning-combobox name={item.value.index} class="set-width"
                                            value={item.value.filterField} options={picklistOptions}
                                            onchange={handleChangeOfPicklist}></lightning-combobox>
                                    </td>

                                    <!-- this is the operator combobox -->
                                    <td>
                                        <lightning-combobox name={item.value.index} class="set-width"
                                            value={item.value.selectedOperator}
                                            options={item.value.availableOperator} onchange={handleChangeOfOperator}>
                                        </lightning-combobox>
                                    </td>
                                    <!-- this is the input value. pass objectApiName to lightning-record-edit-form and use lightning-input-field to display the field. This will display the field along with its datatype.-->
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="set-width">

                                             <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name={objectApiName}>
                                                   <lightning-input-field variant="label-hidden" id={item.value.index} onchange={handleLightningInputField} field-name={item.value.inputFieldName} value={item.value.filterValue}>
                                                   </lightning-input-field>
                                              </lightning-record-edit-form>
                                            
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </template>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Introduce a new style in the css code file.

```
.tr-width {
    width: 40%;
}
```

Use the css class on the specific `td` element of the `HTML table` (as shown in the code snippet below).

```
<!-- this is the input value. pass objectApiName to lightning-record-edit-form and use lightning-input-field to display the field. This will display the field along with its datatype.-->
<td class="tr-width">
    <div class="set-width">
        <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name={objectApiName}>
           <lightning-input-field variant="label-hidden" id={item.value.index} onchange={handleLightningInputField}     field-name={item.value.inputFieldName} value={item.value.filterValue}></lightning-input-field>
      </lightning-record-edit-form>     
    </div>
</td>
```

If you are using multiple sections or lightning-card (i.e., one each for Contract, Contact Address & Customer), then you'll have to update the `td` elements for each section.

Note: Choose the width value that best suits your requirement. It shouldn't be a small value because if the label value is longer, then there'll be a minor vertical alignment issue.

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot! Can you tell me why the problem occurred? And how did applying `css` class to `td` element solve the issue?

Comment: so, all the `td` elements are basically columns in the table. Under each row, the first 2 `td` elements have the `lightning-combobox` which produce the same structure/ styling and hence, no issues (i.e., they align perfectly). But the 3rd `td` element has `lightning-record-edit-form` and this component in each row is producing different HTML structure/ styling (corresponding to checkbox, multi-select, textbox etc.). So, the lightning framework is adjusting their style attributes (i.e., for each recordEditForm) to have best fit within the parent component.

Comment: Now, the css class `set-width` is applied to the elements inside `td` element but not to the `td` element itself. Since, no styling is applied to the `td` element, the browser API is free to choose the best possible height & width for `td` elements depending on the inner element's style.

Comment: By providing a new css class `tr-width` (40%) and applying it specifically on the 3rd `td` element, we are instructing the framework to allocate 40% of the row width (`tr` element) for the 3rd `td` element and the rest of the row width to the remaining `td` elements. Now, because we have fixed the 3rd `td` width, styling of anything that is rendered by the recordEditForm within will be adjusted by the framework/ browser API to be within this specific width. Hope this explains.